# Saving JSON output of a form action call in a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an HTML form with an action that queries an external service.

When I submit the form, I land on the page of the external website. This website only lists JSON output.

Is there any way I can store this object in a JavaScript variable?

```
<form action="http://rdio-service.herokuapp.com//search?q=" method="get" target="_top" >
  Input artist: <input type="text" name="q"><br>
  <button>Find songs</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/85sofgaj/

I've heard about the JQuery method `$.getJSON` but it looks like that only works with local data.

Comment: Sure, register a handler function to the submit event, make an ajax request in background submitting the form values to the given url which will give you the desired json which you can decode. Then return false to prevent the normal submission.

Comment: @arkascha does getJSON works on cross domain?

Comment: @Ankit That depends on a number of factors. Certainly not always, but that is another question, isn't it? Straight forward approach is to grant a request to that domain by means of CORS headers which should be possible, since apparently the OP has control over the form defining system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cross-Domain Ajax without jQuery

OP asks how to query a web service that returns music data in json format. However, the web service is "external" and requires a cross-domain ajax request. Browsers block these requests ("access denied") unless authorized by the server. Typically, the server must set the request header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" specifying who is allowed to make queries and provide a jsonp response. And in this case it appears the web service is not configure for it. For more info see: [MDN HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

One way to overcome this problem is to use a proxy server. The proxy makes the request on behalf of the client.  The example below sends a request to [Yahoo YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) which requests the data for us and then sends it back in jsonp format. (Yahoo, Google, and others offer this service)

**Run the Example to Test:**

I've tried to keep this fairly simple to illustrate the technique. It searches and displays a list of music album titles and covers. Also, it can take a few seconds for the service to respond.

```html
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    #output table { border-collapse: collapse; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px;}
    #output td { border: 1px lightgray solid; padding: 2px;}
    #output img {height: 100px; width: auto; }
</style>

Enter keywords:    
<input id="keyword" type="text" value="Bach"><button onclick="search()">Search...</button>
<div id="output"></div>
    
<script type="text/javascript">

    // jsonp callback
 function callback( obj ) {
     var i, data, html='';
            try {
                data = obj.query.results.json.data;
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                    html += '<tr><td><img src="' + data[i].icon + '"></td><td>' + data[i].name + '</td></tr>';
                }
                html = '<table>' + html + '</table>';
            }
            catch(e) { html = 'No search results.' }
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
 }

    // cross-domain ajax via proxy 
    function search( ) {
        var proxy, query, options, keyword, head, script;
        keyword = document.getElementById('keyword').value;
        keyword = keyword.replace(/\s/g,'+');
        proxy = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
        query = "?q=" + encodeURIComponent( "select * from json where url='http://rdio-service.herokuapp.com//search?q=" + keyword + "'" ); 
        options = '&diagnostics=true&format=json&callback=callback';
        head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement;
 script = document.createElement('script');
 script.type = 'text/javascript';
 script.src = proxy + query + options;
 head.appendChild( script );
    }
    
    search( ); 
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The service returns an array of objects such as:

```
        "data": [
            {
                "object_type": "search_result",
                "id": "t4727843",
                "name": "Didgeridoo",
                "url": "/artist/Duke_Ellington/album/The_Afro-Eurasian_Eclipse_(Remastered)/track/Didgeridoo/",
                "length": "32",
                "radio_id": "sr4727843",
                "type": "track",
                "icon": "http://rdio1img-a.akamaihd.net/album/f/b/d/000000000005ddbf/3/square-200.jpg"
            },
            more records ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can. Why don't you just download result with jQuery get method?
Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btnDownloadJSON').click(function(){
    $.get('http://rdio-service.herokuapp.com//search?q=jay',function(r){
        alert(r.data);
    });
  });
});
```

"r" variable is JavaScript object already. It's parsed from JSON string.